# Obj-C, how do I copy a file with NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to copy some files as part of a backup routine.

I have the following function which gives the location of my files.

```
- (NSString *)getLocalDocumentPath:(NSString*)strFile {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
           NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] 
           stringByAppendingPathComponent:strFile];
    return path;
}
```

Heres my database

```
    NSString *filePath = [self getLocalDocumentPath:@"mydatabase.db"];
```

I want to copy this to a new file called upload.txt

```
    NSString *filePath = [self getLocalDocumentPath:@"upload.txt"];
```

Then later on I download a file.

```
    NSString *filePath = [self getLocalDocumentPath:@"download.txt"];
```

Which I want to copy on top of my original database file.

```
    NSString *filePath = [self getLocalDocumentPath:@"mydatabase.db"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFilemanager defaultManager];
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePath toPath:uploadFilePath error:nil];
```

and if you want to overwrite the database using the download.txt, make an instance of `NSData` and use `- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)useAuxiliaryFile`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to get to know [NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) very well (documentation is linked for you).

The method you'd most likely be most interested in is:

`moveItemAtPath:toPath:error:`

Answer (score 0):

one method could be:
you can read the file contents you want to save in `NSData` then can use:

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)useAuxiliaryFile
```

in which you can replace the path with one your relative file paths you have mentioned for various files.